# Manipulate data in order to return total values using SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Manipulate this data in order to return the total value (Units * Price) of the client holdings in each stock.

```
select  sh.StockCode , sum(sh.Units*sp.PriceNZD) as 'TotalPrice'
 from StockPrice sp
inner join StockHoldings sh  on sp.StockCode=sh.StockCode
group by sh.StockCode
order by TotalPrice desc;
```

> Error: Msg 8117, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for multiply operator.**

Any idea?

Comment: The error message is pretty explicit about the idea behind the problem you are struggling with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast data to proper format:

```
select  sh.StockCode ,
    sum(CAST(sh.Units AS INT)*CAST(sp.PriceNZD AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS TotalPrice
 from StockPrice sp
inner join StockHoldings sh  on sp.StockCode=sh.StockCode
group by sh.StockCode
order by TotalPrice desc;
```

If you are using `SQL Server 2012+` you could use `TRY_CAST` to avoid invalid conversions (invalid data will be treated as NULL)

---

Proper solution: alter your schema and store data with correct datatypes.

Comment: I tried to implement your solution but getting Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'TotalPrice'.

Comment: @Raj Try once again/\

Comment: When i put 'TotalPrice', its showing Incorrect syntax near 'TotalPrice'. If i won't put quote in TotalPrice then Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'from'. I am using SQL server 2014 version so please advise.